# Polypropylene capacitor power supply

Tags: power-supply, transformerless

I found some articles talking about transformerless power supplies, and I have uploaded the schematic of such a circuit. Does anybody have an idea about the pros and cons of such a power supply? Also how to calculate the value of this capacitor "C1" ?

[image]

Comment: This is a non-isolated supply, not hobbiest friendly imho...

Comment: Typical design equations for transformerless supplies can be found in this app note: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00954A.pdf

Comment: @sstobbe Great thing to consider

Answer (score 0):

I've seen these done thusly

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZYdbf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: C1 should be an X1.  We've talked about this before.

Comment: Was this answer wrong?
@RobertEndl

Comment: Sorry, X2.  X1 probably overkill.  I didn't see the X1 in the schematic cuz I'm getting old and careless.

Answer (score -4):

Polypropylene power supplies are a type of capacitive power supplies that supplies a limted current output. The value of the polypropylene capacitor determines the amount of current according to this equation:

X = 1 / (2 π f C)

I = V / X

where

X : capacitor reactance

π : Constant (pi) = 3.14

f : frequency of the main supply (50-60)

C : Capacitance value

I : output current (A)

V : main voltage (110 or 220)

**Pros:**

- constant current power supply is better in some applications like LED Lighting
- wide output voltage range (typically any rated voltage device is able to connect -unless it stands the applied current- )
- More efficient series connections are possible in some applications like LED lighting

**Cons**

- Non-isolated power supply which means rush current can easily destroy your load
- low output current values (Max ~ 350 mA) due to low available capacitance values. or huge number of parallel connected capacitors (10) to output a current of about 1 Amp.

Comment: Why was this answer accepted within a minute of being posted? This discourages competing answers, which improve the quality of the site.

Comment: I was stuck on such a problem when i was designing my PCB for a led lighting project. so i have collected all information I have gained in a simple manner to share my experience with @boddy

Comment: -1. Please explain why you think the circuit is a constant current supply. The circuit limits current by the reactance of C1 but it is not a constant current supply. Instead, it is a loosely voltage-regulated supply.

Comment: Current has only one possible value in each circuit and it also depends on the value of the Polypropylene Capacitor.

Comment: You can use different voltage rated devices unless they are all consuming the same amount of current.

Comment: The terminology is wrong. A constant current supply responds to varying load impedance by varying its output voltage. This supply does nothing of the sort, it loosely maintans a constant output voltage across C2 and will respond to varying load impedances by sourcing varying currents.

Comment: been seeing a lot of these capacitor-based CC drivers recently being incorporated smack dab onto the COB's PCBs, thanks for the rundown on this interesting tech.

Comment: I know that these circuits are not safe enough unless you make a galvanic isolation for the connected load, which means more components and larger size circuit. So I have stated its bros and cons

Comment: I was intending to use it as a power supply unit for my LED street light products, but they have proven to be unsafe, unreliable psu.
@dandavis

Comment: Was this answer wrong?
@dandavis

Comment: not if it got you points!  I like it, but you can't please everyone...

Comment: My question still have not yet upvoted :D so where is the points ?!
@dandavis

Comment: -1 It isn't a constant current supply.  It is a power supply with a limited current output.  Look closely at the given diagram. It includes a zener diode to regulate the voltage.

Comment: My answer was describing polypropylene power supplies in general. zener diode is not a must in this circuit. I have used it many times for LED Lighting, no zeners were used and I can connect different output voltages at the same current rating.  @JRE